# Sizing Dialog Fonts -- Using GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FONT)

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I am an experienced developer who is new to WPF. I appreciate all the flexibility of WPF components, but this flexibility is causing me a little trouble.

Specifically, I want to create a dialog box. When I do this in C++/MFC or C#/Win Forms, my text boxes and the text box fonts are automatically the right size for system dialogs.

But in WPF, I have to hard code both the text box height *and* the font size. This apparently means:

1. I have to guess what font size will best match the user's system font settings for dialog boxes, and my fonts will not adjust to each users' system settings.
2. Even worse, I have to also guess at the best text box size for the current font. This has always been automatic on other platforms.

I'm just wondering how seasoned WPF developers are handling text box and font sizes within a dialog box.

**EDIT:**

In other words, I would like my text boxes to use the font returned by the Windows API calls `GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FONT)`. Is this directly supported by WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding your question, mainly because WPF works *better* than either MFC or Winforms for the scenarios you seem to be asking about.

> 1. I have to guess what font size will best match the user's system font settings for dialog boxes, and my fonts will not adjust to each users' system settings.

WPF uses device-independent metrics. In particular, WPF pixels are always 96 per nominal inch. Of course, depending on user settings, the *actual* size of a WPF "inch" may be more or less than an real inch. But those are the settings under control of the user, specifically designed to do such scaling.

One big advantage of WPF's model is that unlike Winforms, the relative layout of everything stays the same regardless of scaling. In Winforms, different things scale differently, causing line-breaks to happen in different places, text to be truncated, etc.

> 2. Even worse, I have to also guess at the best text box size for the current font. This has always been automatic on other platforms.

The WPF `Window` class has a `SizeToContent` property. If you set this to `Both`, the window will resize itself to exactly contain whatever content you put in it. Is this not what you want?

If the above does not address your specific scenario, please help us understand your scenario by providing [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly the problem you are having, with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: *Better* is not a very precise term when talking about different ways of doing things. Are you aware that Windows has a system setting that is used for the size of text in dialog boxes? This gives dialog boxes a consistent look across applications. You go on to talk about the flexible sizing options but I specifically acknowledged that I appreciated the flexibility of WPF. However, if I want my dialogs to have consistent font sizes with other dialog boxes, then in fact this flexibility appears to not be as good. Regarding your second point, yes that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the size of your Controls to "Auto" like this: `<TextBlock Heigh="Auto" Text="Foobar"/>`, the control's height will then adapt to the content.
This also work for any Height or Width properties on any controls.
Hope I helped ;)